# How do I load dependencies in a soy template?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-templates

In my Google Closure code, I made an enum denoting names of CSS classes and want to use this enum in my soy template:

```
/**
 * Lists a single widget.
 * @param widget The widget to be listed.
 */
{template .singleWidgetListing}
<div class='{app.ui.ClassNames.WIDGET_LISTING}'>
  <span class='{app.ui.ClassNames.WIDGET_LISTING_ITEM}'>{$widget.title}</span>
</div>
{/template}
```

I tried `goog.require('app.ui.ClassNames');` at the top of the soy template file to no avail. What is the standard way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended approach is avoid referencing [globals](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/javascript_usage#globals) in Closure Templates:

> **Note:** Avoid using render-time globals unless absolutely necessary, because it makes for tight coupling between your template and your runtime environment.

A template parameter should be used instead:

```
{namespace myapp}

/**
 * Lists a single widget.
 * @param widget The widget to be listed.
 * @param classNames Map of CSS classes for styling widgets.
 */
{template .singleWidgetListing}
  <div class="{$classNames.WIDGET_LISTING}">
    <span class="{$classNames.WIDGET_LISTING_ITEM}">{$widget.title}</span>
  </div>
{/template}
```

The template would then be called from JavaScript as follows:

```
myapp.singleWidgetListing(
    {widget: myWidgetInstance, classNames: app.ui.ClassNames});
```

See ***[Using Closure Templates in JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/javascript_usage)***.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider passing in the map of CSS classes into your top-level template as injected data (https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/concepts#injecteddata) so that you don't have to pass it through to subtemplates that need it.